# The managed heap cannot be analyzed while garbage collection is in progress

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, iis

I took a [process dump of an application pool process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44387061/185123), `w3wp.exe`, and when I try to open it in VS 2019 & VS 2017 I get:

> The managed heap cannot be analyzed while garbage collection is in progress

[image: screenshot of error]

What does this mean?  When I took the process dump the GC was running and I can't analyze it w/ VS?  If so, how do I ensure I take a process dump when the GC isn't running?

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33854246/909199) which solved it by triggering the dump based on performance counters, using SysInternals ProcDump tool.

That question was about the original `WinDbg / sos.dll` debugging toolset rather than the VS integrated tools, but probably still applies.

In that toolset this case just created a warning about potentially inaccurate results.

There is a [bit of a learning curve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugging-managed-code) but you may be able to get what you want from your current dump file using the `WinDbg / sos.dll` tools.